# Damping factor in active low pass filter

Tags: filter, low-pass

I want to calculate the damping factor of this low-pass filter, where vin=1*sin(2π1000t) Volt. How can i find it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to calculate the damping factor of this low-pass filter

Well, what you have drawn is a first order filter and, first order filters have a damping ratio of 1.

Comment: Thats what i wanted, but one more question ...if the damping factor is one, how can i calculate the damping factor to db/decade for this filter?

Comment: The damping ratio (not factor) does not define the point (nor the slope) where the function starts to fall at 20 dB/decade. It's a 1st order system and it naturally reduces the output by ten for an increase in frequency of ten hence, a reduction by ten = 20 dB (in one decade) = 20 dB/decade.